# C# How to test if IPAddress is in a subnet?

Tags: c#, ip-address

OK, this is a minor issue... but still irritating nonetheless.

In MSVS 2008 .NET 3.5 I IPAdress.Address was a long and I simply used

```
if(subnet == subnetmask.Address & addr.Address) { ... }
```

And then now i just installed MSVS 2010, still using .NET 3.5 but somehow it tells me the IPAddress.Address is obsolete.

I can still wrap a BitConvertor in `BitConverter.ToInt64(subnet.GetAddressBytes(), 0)` but it feels like i am going backwards. Is there a more elegant way or a built-in function to check for subnet?

Thanks.

Comment: This question has been asked a few times, please search next time.

Comment: @leppie: I can't find any duplicate question dealing with the obsolete marking and netmask/subnet calculation. If you can find one, please suggest the possible duplicate.

Comment: I searched but could not find the answer I need. I just felt that the we did not manage to uphold the spirit and cleverness in subnet masking technique as it does not seem to be implemented in .NET. I was hoping we are not left with comparing byte blocks in a for-loop.

Comment: @Jake: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499269/how-to-check-if-an-ip-address-is-within-a-particular-subnet?

Comment: @leppie i saw that already. I found it via google first, not satisfied, I come over to SO and found that post which points to the same article. It is not immediately obvious that the method is the only justified viable method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for `IPAddress.Address` to be marked as obsolete is:

> This property has been deprecated. It is address family dependent.
>   Please use IPAddress.Equals method to perform comparisons.
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202

With IPv6 coming, depending on specific features of IPv4 should be regarded as obsolete. Your workaround has the same problem - dependency on IPv4. I think that you have two options:

- Keep your application IPv4-only and supress the obsolete warning.
- Find out how to make the functionality work in both IPv6 and IPv4.